# array to string conversion using a function for to convert an array

Tags: php, for-loop, ascii

The intention of the code is to get a specific section of all the numbers, get them to be in pairs, and translate them from ascci to dec. example 55 has to be 7

I have this code:

```
$code = "34002500032323255575249480161649"; 
$codeneeded = substr($code, 9, 16);
$array = ascii_to_dec($codeneeded);
echo "$array<br>";
```

this way i can get all this 3232325557524948, and using a function to convert this number from ascci to dec. getting them to pair up for this convertion like: 32 32 32 55 54 52 49 48.

the function im calling is this one:

```
function ascii_to_dec($str)
{
  for ($i = 0, $j = strlen($str); $i < $j; $i= $i+2) {
  $y=$i+1;

  $dec_array[] = chr($str{"$i$y"});
  return $dec_array;
}
```

and it shows this when im trying to run the program:

Notice: Array to string conversion on line 23
Array

Comment: What language is this? PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is wrong.

This line:

```
$str{"$i$y"};
```

assumes these values:

```
$str{01};  // string offset 01
$str{23};  // string offset 23
$str{45};  // string offset 45
(...)
```

but in your string sample offsets 23, 45, etc don't exist. I guess that you don't see any error because you missed closing `if` parenthesis, and your code return only first `$str{01}`. In this case, your returned array has only one element with converted `3`. Otherwise, you have an array with converted `3` and 7 empty elements.

Change your code in this way:

```
function ascii_to_dec( $str )
{
    for( $i = 0, $j = strlen($str); $i < $j; $i= $i+2 )
    {
        $dec_array[] = chr( substr( $str, $i, 2) );
    }
    return $dec_array;
}

$array = ascii_to_dec( $codeneeded );
print_r( $array );
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ' '
    [1] => ' '
    [2] => ' '
    [3] => 7
    [4] => 9
    [5] => 4
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 0
)
```

Otherwise, if you want to return the converted string, replace `return $dec_array;` with `return implode( $dec_array );` or with `return trim( implode( $dec_array ) );` and use `echo` to output returned string.

Comment: it worked! thank you c:

Answer (score 3):

Your error is on how you try to output your array. You can't echo an array in php.

instead of

```
echo "$array<br/>";
```

you should use something like

```
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Or `echo implode('',$array);`